# Find the coefficient of $x^{80}$ in the power series expansion $\dfrac{x^2(1+x^2+x^5)}{(1-x)^2(1+x)}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, power-series

Find the coefficient of $x^{80}$ in the power series expansion $$\dfrac{x^2(1+x^2+x^5)}{(1-x)^2(1+x)}.$$

---

I don't know how to find coefficients in power series, solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know the coefficients of the power series $\frac{1}{1-x}$?

Comment: @vadim123  The power series $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ is just $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \cdots,$ right?

Comment: Next question: Do you know the coefficients of the power series $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$?

Comment: @vadim123  That's $1+x^2+x^4+ \cdots,$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it as $$\frac{x^2(1+x^2+x^5)}{(1-x)(1-x^2)}=x^2(1+x^2+x^5)\left(\sum_{h=0}^\infty x^h\right)\left(\sum_{s=0}^\infty x^{2s}\right)=\\=(x^2+x^4+x^7)\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\#\left\{(h,s)\,:\,0\le h,s\wedge h+2s=k\right\}=$$

if you call $a_k:=\#\left\{(h,s)\,:\,0\le h,s\wedge h+2s=k\right\}$, it continues as
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (a_{k-7}+a_{k-4}+a_{k-2})x^k$$

So, you just have to compute $a_{73}+a_{76}+a_{78}$. You can easily see that a pair $(h,s)$ is uniquely determined by the choice of $s$ such that $0\le 2s\le k$. Hence $a_k=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }k<0\\ 1+\left\lfloor\frac k2\right\rfloor&\text{if }k\ge0\end{cases}$.

Comment: So the coefficient of $x^{80}$ would be $41,$ using your formula, right?

Comment: Uhm... Since $a_{78}$ alone is $40$, I doubt it.

Comment: Oops, I got a little mixed up.  To clear things up, the coefficient of $x^{80}$ would be $a_{73}+a_{76}+a_{78},$ correct?

Comment: That's what I said.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the confusion.  So the coefficient of $x^{80}$ would be $116,$ yes?

Answer (score 2):

HINT
You can decompose it into partial fractions and get $$x^4+x^3+2x^2+3x+4-\frac{23}{4}(1-x)^{-1}+\frac 14(1+x)^{-1}+\frac 32(1-x)^{-2}$$

Then apply the generalised binomial theorem

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^2(1+x^2+x^5)}{(1-x)^2(1+x)}=x^2(1+x^2+x^5)\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{2}{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\right)$$
then use the following
$${\frac {1}{1-x^2}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }x^{2n}$$

$${\frac {1}{(1-x)^{2}}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }nx^{n-1}$$